# How can I run a command on disk error?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, shell, debian, kernel

System: Debian Squeeze

What's it for: A System where any new disk is DoD Wiped.

I'm looking for a method to fire a command on a disk error that the kernel throws, sometimes we get bad disks and it just needs to be scraped.

Common lines in the logs are

```
Jan 15 10:34:33 drivekiller9k kernel: [339274.100020] usb 2-3: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 51
Jan 15 10:34:33 drivekiller9k kernel: [339274.233729] sd 176:0:0:1: [sdl] Unhandled error code
Jan 15 10:34:33 drivekiller9k kernel: [339274.233733] sd 176:0:0:1: [sdl] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jan 15 10:34:33 drivekiller9k kernel: [339274.233737] sd 176:0:0:1: [sdl] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 34 b8 70 00 00 f0 00
Jan 15 10:34:33 drivekiller9k kernel: [339274.233781] __ratelimit: 20 callbacks suppressed
Jan 15 10:34:33 drivekiller9k kernel: [339274.233815] lost page write due to I/O error on sdl
```

I would like a method where I could just run a shell script to kill the wiping process and write to a log, what would be the proper method to do this?

Comment: I was thinking of a log watcher, using tail and awk

Comment: You could use something like [swatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [smartmontools](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/) to monitor your disk health, using the provided `smartd` demon. Some [examples](http://blog.shadypixel.com/monitoring-hard-drive-health-on-linux-with-smartmontools/).

Comment: That would work, but all the drives are connected over USB 3.0, so SMART data cannot be accessed

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `Shell execute` ACTION of rsyslog to trigger actions (e.g. your recovery script) on certain log message entries. See `man rsyslog.conf` for details.

Comment: Hrm, that does sound nice. I have switched over to badblocks first pass with a read-write zero test, -- I'll look into rsyslog right away, this looks perfect. -- Now to figure out how to unlock the dying drive while I'm not around

Comment: what do you mean by `unlock`? you want  to remove/shut down the drive?

Comment: Yes, When a drive is in a locked up state, (IOWait) I would like to just eject the drive and kill the wiping process/write to a log

Comment: in cases like that I use an USB switch to simply power off the device. Since they removed the code from the kernel to power off the device directly on the host system. Further details are [here](http://superuser.com/questions/176319/hard-reset-usb-in-ubuntu-10-04/528492#528492)