# How can I hardreset a modem or the port under Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, modem

I have a device (a modem) connected to a USB port (/dev/ttyACM0, Ubuntu 12.04) to dial a phone number, which only works if I perform the ultimate reset (taking device out of USB port, waiting some seconds and plug it in again).

My question: Is it possible to solve this on Linux by software, i.e. to 'reset' the modem as if it has been plugged out or to reset the USB port itself (disconnect power?), so the modem is being reset as it has been plugged out and in again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think long time ago there was a way to switch off USB devices by software only. Then people started to fiddle with power of USB disks screwing the USB driver stack. After all the kernel gods removed software switch off capabilities.

The only way I currently know about to completely power off USB devices is a hybrid hard- and software solution:

[Hard Reset USB in Ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/176319/hard-reset-usb-in-ubuntu-10-04/528492#528492)